# React Router Strict Mode Causing SocketIO to process Emit Twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

When I tried to implement React Router, it seems that I am getting duplicate elements because the `socket.on()` event is now executing twice.

the router

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

the route:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <TablesView />,
  }
]);
```

and the code for `TablesView`

```
function TablesView() {
  const [games, setGames] = useState([]);
  ...

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("room_made", function (msg) {
      // TODO Fix duplicate socket
      var gameID = msg["gameID"];
      var chairs = msg["chairs"];
      setGames((oldGames) => [...oldGames, { gameID, chairs }]);
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
      setIsConnected(false);
    });

    return () => {
      socket.off("connect");
      socket.off("disconnect");
      socket.off("pong");
    };
  }, []);

return (
...
);
}
```

I checked the server side code, and nothing is getting emitted twice. So for some reason, it's just hitting the `room_made` event twice.

But if I remove `React.Strictmode`, it works fine. Why is this?

Any wisdom would be appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

This behavior is typical of Strictmode in the development environment. It invokes certain functions twice to help detect unwanted side effects. See more info in the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html).

This behavior will not occur in production. If you want to stop it from happening in the development environment as well, you can remove the Strictmode tag.

Comment: This unfortunately is not accurate anymore. Refer to the docs to make sure you write your code with appropriate cleanup functions.

https://socket.io/how-to/use-with-react